# Android not parsing JSON Array

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am currently trying to parse a JSON Array in my code but the problem is it never enters the try block.

Here is my code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();

        String json =  jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://hills.ccsf.edu/~jpark41/ViB/sample.json");


        if(json != null) {

 Log.i("JSON: ", "NOT NULL"); // This log executes!!

            try
            {
                Log.i("we: ", " out here"); // This does not!!

                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                JSONArray jsar = new JSONArray(json);

                Iterator<String> iter = jObj.keys();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    String key = iter.next();
                    try {
                        JSONObject value = (JSONObject)jObj.get(key);
                        id = value.getString("id");
                        thumb = value.getString("thumb");
                        media = value.getString("media");
                        title = value.getString("title");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // Something went wrong!
                    }
                    now_playing = id;
                    earned = title;

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.i("we NOT: ", " out here");
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

"we out here" is never logged, only "we NOT out here". Why is the try block never executing? I don't have much experience parsing JSON with android so I'm sure I'm just missing something. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the stack trace? If 'we NOT out here' is getting printed, then an exception is being thrown. The stack trace will be helpful in identifying the problem.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in the debugger?

Comment: My assumption would be that `getJSONFromURL` is failing or returning null.

Comment: You'd save yourself a lot of trouble if you use a framework to parse the Json into POJOs for you.  Look at Gson or Jackson

Comment: Please post your logcat output.

Comment: Please show us your JSON Object/Array. It could be either  JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json); or   JSONArray jsar = new JSONArray(json);  can not be both at the same time.

Comment: @Chitrang That was it. When i commented out the JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json); and swapped out the iterator for a basic for loop it all worked. Thanks for everyones help.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. Happy coding :)

Comment: @nasch I will accept in 22 hours when the system allows me.

Comment: that is some terrible logging standard you have, you should use a standard Log TAG for sanity, using different tags you won't see the logs under a consistent tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i commented out the JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json); and swapped out the iterator for a basic for loop it all worked. Thanks for everyones help.